# SSL handshake error when connecting by websocket using encrypted connection

Tags: javafx-2, tyrus, java-websocket

I use **Tyrus** webSocket implementation to connect to the server from my **JavaFX** application. When I try to establish connection over SSL I get this error: **javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake error has occurred - more data needed for validating the certificate**

I tried to use a dummy certificate and host verification as described in [Disable Certificate Validation in Java SSL Connections](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/) but to no avail.

There is also not much information on Tyrus documentation.

I simply don't know what to do!

**P.S.** For what it's worth I managed to get around this issue by using [Grizzly client](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.tyrus/tyrus-container-grizzly-client)

```
//final WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
final ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();

URI uri = URI.create(this.uri + "?" + System.currentTimeMillis());
session = client.connectToServer(this, uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install a certificate chain. I believe you can import the signing certificate using keytool -import. Have you setup the certificate store?

Comment: No, I'm not sure how to do this